# Minimizing sample variance of $n$ functions

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

$f_n$, $i=1,\dots, n$ are $n$ functions. I would like to minimize the sample variance of these functions subject to a linear constraint:

$$\text{minimize}\quad \frac{1}{N}\sum (f_i(x_i) - f_\text{mean}(x))^2\\
\text{subject to}\quad \sum x_i = R$$

where $f_\text{mean}(x) = \frac{1}{N}\sum f_i(x_i)$.

How do I solve this problem? When I use the Lagrange Multipliers theorem, the partial derivates of the objective are zero, implying $\lambda = 0$. What is going on?

Comment: I'm guessing your trying to find minimizing values of $x_i$ with $f_i$ fixed, not minimizing values of $f_i$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yup, that's correct.

Comment: Vaguely stated, you need to make $f_i(x_i)$, $i=1,\ldots,n$ as close together as possible.

Comment: Yes, and I need to calculate $x_i$ to make that happen...

Comment: So you have a *discrete* list of pairs $(x_i,f_i(x_i))$?

Comment: No, all $x_i$ are continuous and positive.

Comment: Since changing $x_i$ does not affect $f_j(x_j)$ for $j\ne i$, the problem reduces to minimizing $\sum_{i=1}^N (y_i-\bar y)^2$ subject to the constraings $y_i\in S_i$, where $S_i$ is the range of $f_i$. ${}\qquad{}$